# Table sort problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, tablesorter

I am trying to use sortable, a jQuery plugin and while it works great I noticed that when I have a missing value in a column in addition to other values that start either with a letter or a number, for some reason the empty cell appears in the middle in DESC sort, instead of dropping down as expected.

Here's the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HvKmP/17/). Please sort last column.

What do I need to modify to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a bug that it doesn't sort mixed case of numbers and alphanumeric ones properly. E.g. if you put "zzz" instead of space, it still stays in middle.

Here's a workaround:

**Updated** to fix sort in other columns
http://jsfiddle.net/HvKmP/31/

Comment: This is somewhat what I was looking for. It works partially, though. It places the  blank properly, but it when it groups letters and numbers, one set is DESC while the other one  is ASC...

Comment: Yeah it goes through all columns. But you can add additional check to go thru the required columns only.

Comment: I also noticed that your modification affected the sort in other columns... :(

Comment: Clicking of the column headers does not produce a sort any longer.

Comment: I think `console.log` was the issue. It wasn't working in IE and when I turned on debugger tools, it worked. I commented it out now: http://jsfiddle.net/HvKmP/31/

Comment: You nailed it! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I've forked a version of [tablesorter on github](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter) and added an alphanumeric sort as the default sort. Check if out if you want :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".tablesorter").tablesorter().find('td:empty').html('&nbsp;');
```

[The updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/HvKmP/18/)

Comment: I can still see the blank cell in the middle of the rows. it should be either on top or the bottom when the column is sorted.

Comment: here you have to have a logic, what do you want to sort, string or numbers ? It's for knowing what type will be the empty one, string or number

Comment: Can't it be made omnivorous? It sorts OK when it is numbers and letters but it does not seem to know what to do with a blank value.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/HvKmP/19/

There are two things to note. First, your final column had 's22' and 'a45'. Removing the letters fixed the sorting. Secondly, what's hapenning is that the sorter reads the first row and see's a number and is assuming the rest will be numerical too. The sorting for numbers is sorting the numbers, then leaving the non-numeric values as unsorted.

Comment: It should short properly without modifying values. Blank cell should be on TOP or the BOTTOM, not in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is in the javascript you are using is not sorting is the td's contain numbers as the first letter, try changing this and you will see it working.

Comment: Yes, I know it is in the JS, but where?